# Saving a value on android

Tags: android, android-file

I want to save a String value on Android and have access to this
String every time the application starts.

For instance the String value will have the user's name which he has created by
his own. And after restaring the api he would have this name already on the top.
Like a cookie or sth. How to save such file on android memory ?

Can someone guide me?

Comment: Try googling or searching here - `android configuration save`

Comment: you have two options: 1. use `SharedPreferences` 2. use database

Comment: Hi @karas, Please check out my answer below, just now realized you may  not be notified on my answer this way. Tell me if it helped.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
private static final String PREFS_NAME = "YOUR_TAG";
private static final String DATA_TAG = "DATA_TAG";
private static final String data = "oh, what a data!";

//init
SharedPreferences mSettings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

//commit
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();    
editor.putString(DATA_TAG, data);
editor.commit();

//clear
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();    
editor.clear();  
editor.commit();

//get
String data= mSettings.getString(DATA_TAG, null);
```

If you would like to store your data not only on your local device but share this data across the devices for the same user or even across different platforms you can use a simple API of [Skiller SDK](http://www.skiller-games.com). I am ofcourse from Skiller, for full disclosure.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to only store the data locally, use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).  If you're looking to have this data persist across multiple devices (always available for this user), check out [Swarm's Cloud Data](http://swarmconnect.com/cloud_data), which provides a simple set/get (like SharedPreferences) for storing data in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is all about.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to implement is, store in shredpreferences, read it on lauch of your application. [Shared Preference API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). HEre is an [example](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/63.html)
 on how to use SharedPreferences